# Why are we taking the absolute value in this problem?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I do not understand why absolute values are used in the following problem. 
[image]

If someone can explain why, without using complex mathematical lingo, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The absolute value is introduced in order to use the squeeze theorem.  We want to establish that
\begin{equation}
-r\leq \frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \leq r
\end{equation}
so that we can just take the limits of the upper and lower bounds and use the squeeze theorem.  But this is equivalent to
\begin{equation}
\left\vert\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right\vert \leq r,
\end{equation}
(because if the absolute value of a number is no larger than $r$, then that number must lie in the interval $[-r,r]$) which is what the solution's author shows.

Comment: I see what's going on. Thank you very much for the illuminating response! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to express that a value is tiny, you can write

$$v<\epsilon$$ where $\epsilon$ is a small positive number.

But doing so, you do not exclude the cases of $v$ negative and not tiny at all.

To fix tat, you need to use a bilateral bracketing,

$$-\epsilon<v<\epsilon$$ which is also written

$$|v|<\epsilon.$$